Java FXML, change label text, pause GUI for x seconds, then change label text again
I'm currently working on a Pokémon fangame, and I have a problem (not the last).
So here is the thing, since it's a round by round game, I have to do this:

Decide which Pokémon attack first.
Change label text on GUI to inform the user of what's going on.
Wait for x seconds.
Then the other Pokémon attack.
Change label text on GUI to inform the user of what's going on.
Wait for x seconds.

All of that is working perfectly fine, except the Wait for x seconds part, the first label change is straight up skipped.
Here is a simple version of my code:
public class BattleController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label lblInfoBattle;
    
    private boolean firstAttack;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //things when the scene appear on the screen
    }
    
    //Calling this method when clicking on an attack
    public void btnAttackClicked() {
        //Here I decide who attack first and other things...
        
        String myCustomText = ("The first pokemon attack");
        firstAttack = true;

        //Then I'm calling this method I created
        waitForSeconds(myCustomText);

        //Then the other Pokémon attack and many things... 

        myCustomText = ("The second pokemon attack");
        firstAttack = false;

        //Then I'm calling this method I created
        waitForSeconds(myCustomText);
    }

    private void waitForSeconds(String myCustomText){
       //Here I want to put the pause function;

       //Here is my currently solution
       if (firstAttack) {
            lblInfoBattle.setText(myCustomText);
        } else {
            PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
            pt.setOnFinished(e -> lblInfoBattle.setText(myCustomText));
            pt.play();
        }
    }
}

I've tried -> Thread.sleep, Timer/TimerTask, TimeLine, TranslateTransition.
I'm just looking for a simple way to create a pause without freezing the GUI.

Timeline should work (as should PauseTransition). Show what you tried.

With TimeLine i tried to animate an image (referencing to a pokemon):
Timeline tm = new Timeline();
tm.add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10000),
new KeyValue (myImageView.translateXProperty(), 25)));
tm. setCycleCount(2);
tm.setAutoReverse(true);               
tm.setOnFinished(e -> lblInfoBattle.setText(myCustomText); 
tm.play();

But it played both animation at the same time, and of course the label change was skipped

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Post the code in the question, not in comments

Possible duplicate: periodic background task, or pause transition.

Yeah sorry for not being clear, i edited my question with an minimalist example.
It's working but only for 2 label changes and sometimes i have to do more than 2.
What im expecting is :
When i call the "waitForSeconds()" method, it pauses the gui so that the user can actually see the text change for multiple seconds

The problem is that the code after the first call to waitForSeconds() (including the second call to waitForSeconds()) is executed immediately. If you want to use a PauseTransition for this, you need to arrange for everything that happens after the pause to be executed in the onFinished handler of the PauseTransition. Other options (e.g. a Timeline or even AnimationTimer may be easier for this, depending on what you're doing that you haven't shown.

Ah, ok i see, i have to include the "second attack part" in a setOnFinished PauseTransition, yeah it make sense. i'll try that, thanks you for the help ^^

It worked ! It's kind of confusing because when i want to do more than 2 text change, i have to include a PauseTransition in another PauseTransition, but it works !  Maybe there is an easier solution but for now I'll stick with this one, thanks you!

Community wiki answer:
The owner solved the problem by himself in the comments.
He included the code to execute in the setOnFinished() of the PauseTransition, which is the correct way to go.
Original comment:
Ah, ok i see, i have to include the "second attack part" in a setOnFinished PauseTransition, yeah it make sense. i'll try that, thanks you for the help ^^ –
killian GRAS
CommentedJul 2 at 22:13
